# android getting contact first name

Tags: android, contacts

Hi I am trying to get a contacts first name. I know how to get a contacts full name, but I cannot figure out how obtain just the name. any ideas?

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
       if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String name =  cur.getString(2);
        // do something with the name
       }
    } finally {
       cur.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't personally tried this, but you may have to do a further `RawContacts.CONTENT_URI` query against the `PersonLookup.LOOKUP_KEY` from the first query, allowing you to retrieve the [StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html) field.